# Extract black and white raw image in PDF to jpg and tiff

Tags: .net, pdf, imaging

I have a task to extract black and white (1 bpc) image from PDF to jpg and tiff using .Net.
But I got an exception when creating a bitmap from the memory steam.

The below is parts of my code

```
PdfImageXObject imageObject = imageData.GetImage();
if (imageObject == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Image could not be read.");
}
else
{
    ImageData image = ImageDataFactory.Create(imageObject.GetImageBytes());
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(image.GetData()))
    {
        Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(ms); //Exception threw from here, and the message was "Parameter is not valid."
        //do the conversion.....
    }
}
```

I use iText 7 to handle the PDF parts and the program works properly on grayscale and color images.
I know the 1bpc images are classificed as rawimage, but have no clue on how to handle them.
And I tried to append a header to the byte array returned from image.GetData() and expect the bitmap know what are they but with no luck.

Could anyone give me suggestion?

Comment: Thank KJ. I checked iText.Layout.Element.Image's API, this class have no way to export or convert to general format image. My goal is to extract the images out of the PDF which is different from the reference link.

Comment: I roughly got your idea, but in this case I got a B&W txt  and I have to convert it to jpg or tiff on my own?

Comment: I got it. Thank KJ.

Comment: iText seems unable to handle my case. I just shift my direction to how to decode the steam into normal image as you said. Here is what I found from my target object <</Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Name /Im0
/Filter /CCITTFaxDecode
/Width 2429
/Height 3584
/BitsPerComponent 1
/ColorSpace /DeviceGray
/DecodeParms <</K -1 /Columns 2429>>
/Length 8 0 R>>

Comment: Thank KJ. I did what I want last Friday. My solution is to use pdfbig to get the raw byte array as itext can only give a decoded array but using wrong decoder. Then I use bitmiracle to save the raw byte array into a tiff file with correct header. As you said CCITTFaxDecode is the same as group 4 compression, after I put the correct header Windows' default image viewer or bitmap can load it properly.

Comment: If bitmap can load, my conversion code can be used. I guess there is no universal solution  or library to handle all type? For now, I only targeted on the PDF scanned from printer, and might have to add more manual handling later.

Comment: Nice to know that. I might have to deal with that someday. My service is not rollout yet and not sure how much variation pdf image out there. My team's current phrase is aim to deal with some general types.